# Using specific column and cells in Excel workbook using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Python scrub here and I have an excel spreadsheet I'm importing into my Python script using Pandas and I'm having some issues with the 2D Arrays. Basically, I have the Excel workbook under the variable "workbook", then I'm using the pd.Dataframe command to store only a certain column of data, but I don't understand how I can go down the list of cells one by one in that column? Ultimately, I'm looking to create a loop that will allow me to input each row one at a time, then putting that information into a dictionary, then use that dictionary in a function to automate some data backups.

```
Workbook = (my excel file path)
eRead = pd.read_excel(workBook, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
eIP = pd.DataFrame(eRead, columns= ['IP'])
```

print(eIP) shows the 3 entries + the header of the excel document. I apologize if I didn't explain this correctly but as I stated, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand your goal here, but here is one way to iterate on rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

eIP = pd.DataFrame({"IP": ["a", "b", "c"]})

for _, row in eIP.iterrows():
    print(row.values[0])

# Output
a
b
c
```

You can also get a dictionary of the values like this:

```py
print(eIP.to_dict()["IP"])
# Output
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```